# change gb4e enumeration in only one chapter

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I am using `gb4e` for glossing examples in my thesis. I would like to set the example number back to zero for an appendix. I assume some variation of Alan Munn's solution at [gb4e enumeration format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116798/gb4e-enumeration-format) might work for me, but but how to format it so that it only affects the one chapter, rather than all chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply reset the `exx` counter just after the `\appendix` command:

```
\appendix
\setcounter{exx}{0}
```

MWE (borrowed from linked answer)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll born be?ettef\={a}q.e yek.i ?az aqv\={a}m.a\v{s} be \v{s}ahr.e per\={a}g moh\={a}jerat kard\\
     Born with.EZ one.INDEF from relatives.CL-3SG to city.EZ Prague move did.3SG \\
\glt `Born moved to the city of Prague with one of his relatives.'
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll born be?ettef\={a}q.e yek.i ?az aqv\={a}m.a\v{s} be \v{s}ahr.e per\={a}g moh\={a}jerat kard\\
     Born with.EZ one.INDEF from relatives.CL-3SG to city.EZ Prague move did.3SG \\
\glt `Born moved to the city of Prague with one of his relatives.'
\end{exe}

\chapter{}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll born be?ettef\={a}q.e yek.i ?az aqv\={a}m.a\v{s} be \v{s}ahr.e per\={a}g moh\={a}jerat kard\\
     Born with.EZ one.INDEF from relatives.CL-3SG to city.EZ Prague move did.3SG \\
\glt `Born moved to the city of Prague with one of his relatives.'
\end{exe}

\appendix
\setcounter{exx}{0}

\chapter{}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll born be?ettef\={a}q.e yek.i ?az aqv\={a}m.a\v{s} be \v{s}ahr.e per\={a}g moh\={a}jerat kard\\
     Born with.EZ one.INDEF from relatives.CL-3SG to city.EZ Prague move did.3SG \\
\glt `Born moved to the city of Prague with one of his relatives.'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]